# Size based scale problems in point displacement styling

Tags: qgis, style, multipoint

I am trying to style shapes for a continuous variable by size in point displacement. I used point displacement because I have multiple sampling events for sites. I styled my categorical data with colors. Then I ran into  problem when scaling the sizes of my points based on my continuous data (EP Chinook):

I think that my 2 data points for the site "Camping rio Llaima" are being averaged, and displayed as 1 dot size (see attribute table).

[image]

Since the values are 11 and 115 the dots at this site should be a very different size, considering the other point with a value of 58 looks similar to these points.